# UIView with shadow

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to create a shadow around a simple UIView object which is added on top of a UIViewController's view.
what's the most straight forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, be sure to import the Quartz Core library:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Next, add the following lines to set up the shadow's properties:

```
someView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
someView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0f,10.0f);
someView.layer.shadowOpacity = .5f;
someView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
```

Keep in mind that if you have that view's clipsToBounds property set to YES, the shadow won't appear.

Comment: Right on. Thanks! I tried that but I couldn't figure out why it never worked and indeed the problem was the clipsToBounds property set to YES. One more question is what if I want the shadow to be on all 4 sides of the View? I think this only lets you have 2 sides at the time by changing the shadowOffset... Anyway, Thanks again!

Comment: If both the offset and the radius are 10, the shadow is hidden behind someView. If you want the shadow on all 4 sides of someView, change the radius to be greater than the offset (or change the offset to 0 to have an even shadow around someView).

Answer (score 3):

It took me some time to figure it out. Code works perfect but you should import quartz

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```